# Can I use wildcard ssl cert on subdomain while using basic ssl cert on domain?

Tags: ssl, cors, wildcard-subdomain

I do have Symantec Secure Site installed on domain.com. Recently wanted to load some resources from sub.domain.com however there was a CORS problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on webkit browsers therefore I would like to buy and install RapidSSL Wildcard cert on sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com etc. Will this work ? Will it be "CORS compatible"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will this work ?

It will likely work at the SSL/TLS level.

Symantec Secure Site probably issued a certificate for `example.com` and `www.example.com`.

RapidSSL Wildcard certificate will work for `web2.example.com`, `web3.example.com`, etc. RapidSSL Wildcard probably overlaps with Symantec's certificate, but it should not be a problem since you are configuring it at the server.

> Will it be "CORS compatible"?

Its hard to say since you have not provided the domain, and you have not provided any code.

An "origin" is a `{protocol,domain,port}` triplet (protocol is called a scheme). Depending on the code, you may have a same origin, or you may not. See *Origin Determination Rules* at [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: On `https://www.example.com:443/` I would like to load resources from `https://sub1.example.com:443/` etc. Based on [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) this should not work because of "Different host (exact match required)". However adding this: `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.example.com:443/"` to server config(subdomain virtualhost) should override it, am I right ?